# Is there a way to spread a cell into multiple columns showing a single component in react-table?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have a `react-table` but for one of the rows I want to show a single component that spreads for more than one column **maintaining the `columns` layout** like in the picture bellow:

[image]

I thought of defining my columns like this with a special value (-1000):

```
{
    Header: () => <span className={styles.tableHeaderCell}>Column 1</span>,
    accessor: "val1",
    style: style.columnGrowEqually,
    Cell: ({ row }) => {
        const data = row.original
        const [value, setValue] = useState(data.val1);
        return (
            value === -1000 ?
            <div className={styles.emptyCell}></div>
            :
            <span className={styles.cell}>{value}</span>
        );
    }
},
```

but I don't know how to make a cell spread more than one column and show a single React component.